# Webpack Extract CSS for Production, Inline for Development

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader, react-hot-loader

I modified the [React Hot Loader Boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) `webpack.config.js` so that it will export CSS into a separate file by adding the module:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: /src/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'style',
      'css!postcss!sass'
    )
}
```

As well as the plugin:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
```

Here is the full [webpack.config file](http://codepen.io/dougmacklin/pen/dMGggX?editors=0010) for reference. While this correctly exports `app.css` when I run `webpack`, it kills the hot reload functionality for development. If I revert the module to:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    include: /src/,
    loaders: [
      'style',
      'css',
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass'
    ]
}
```

Hot reload works fine ([adjusted webpack.config](http://codepen.io/dougmacklin/pen/ONMBBO?editors=0010)).

What is the best setup to easily switch between these two when I'm developing vs. exporting production ready code? In my mind, if I could use `npm start` (which just calls `node server.js`) to automatically use development mode, and then run `webpack` or `webpack -p` to automatically use production, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `process.env.NODE_ENV` like what a typical React app usually use. like,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
    ...
```

and in the configuration file:

```
var cssLoader;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    cssLoader = { <... your production-use loader setup> }
} else {
    cssLoader = { <... your development-use loader setup> }
}
...
loaders: [cssLoader, <...other loaders>]
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that it works better if I use `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` as then simply running `webpack` will default to non-development (my production one). I believe you included an unnecessary `!` in your conditional, could you remove it? Here is my revised [webpack.config.js](http://codepen.io/dougmacklin/pen/KzVrQP?editors=0010)